# Remote Breakpoint without local jars

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

Can I set a breakpoint in the remote debuggee without having local jars?

I have an

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.authenticate(SimpleSecurityManager.java:436)

Now I'd have to create a Java project, add the JBoss jars and create a method entry breakpoint.
Can I skip this? Shouldn't it be possible to just say Eclipse, add a method entry breakpoint at the method of the exception? Does the JVM TI support this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will need the class file atleast to set a break point.